# How to crop bmp file in C

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

I'm trying to learn image processing in C I got a library for bitmap files a BMP I/O library
two primary functions, saveBMP and readBMP we have I can't figure out how to split or trim a part of BMP file with RGB 255 255 255.
[library bmpio link](https://gofile.io/d/CwrH77)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bmpio.h>

unsigned char pic[2000][2000][3];

int main(){
    int width,height;
    readBMP("img.bmp",&width,&height,pic);
    row=findsatr(width,height);
    col=findsoton(width,height);
    splitrow(row);
    splitcol(col);
    trim(row,col);
    saveBMP(pic,width,height,"out.bmp");
    return 0;
}

findcol(int width,height){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i>width;i++){
        for(j=0;j>height;j++){
            if(pic[i][j][0]==255&&pic[i][j][1]==255&&pic[i][j][2]==255){
                return j;
            }
            else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

findrow(int width,int height){
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j>height;j++){
        for(i=0;i>width;i++){
            if(pic[i][j][0]==255&&pic[i][j][1]==255&&pic[i][j][2]==255){
                return i;
            }
            else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's difficult to understand how it works and I don't know how to delete the white part of BMP.

```
int splitcol(int height){
    

}

int splitrow(int height){
    

}


int trim(int width,int height){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to capture a rectangular part of your image with top left corner at w1, h1 and bottom right corner w2, h2.

```
unsigned char pic[2000][2000][3];
unsigned char pic2[2000][2000][3];
int width = w2-w1;
int height=h2-h1;
for(int i=0;i<=width;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=height;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<=3;k++)
            pic2[i][j][k] = pic[i+width][j+height][k];

saveBMP(pic2,width,height,"out.bmp")
```